# Saving an R-Script results in empty file

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

I have recently started using R for uni. I want to save my code using either *save as* or *ctrl+s*. However, the saved file is empty more often than not. For some reason, the files save normally on a few occasions. However, they also became empty after saving changes to the script.

I couldn't find any solution for the problem, neither here nor anywhere else.

I am using RStudio installed via Anaconda on an Windows 10 x64 Notebook, if that helps.

Thanks a lot for the responses! I'd be glad to provide more details if needed!

This is what the saved files look like from File Explorer:

[image: list of seven files of "R-Datei" type, only one of which has a non-zero size]

Answer (score 4):

I just meet the exactly same problem. I solved it by checking and changing RStudio -> File -> "Save as Encoding" from "ISO-8859-1 (System default)" to "UTF-8", then the file was saved. I'm trying to recover my previous 0kb files...

Answer (score 0):

*i couldn't reproduce the error* but i also don't like to use the anaconda environment.

if the problem is saving the text file than may i suggest to do just that and save the code in a regular .txt file?

if this is not an option you can try to find out what happens if you save the r studio code on a different drive (or usb/flash drive)

###########################################################

**EDIT 14.07.2022**

Interestingly enough, just today (14.07.2022) I had the same problem. After installing R 4.2.1 everything worked fine until I changed the encoding (from utf-8 to windows 1252), at which point all the files in my project were overwritten and are now empty. Changing back to an older version of R (4.1.3) allowed me to display/save/use all scripts again (from backups).

Using the answer provided by @Shidan it is possible to open the data in R-4.2.1 as well.

This problem does not seem to be connected to Anaconda but an encoding issue between Rstudio and any R distribution above (and including) 4.2.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The same problem occurs if I change the file's extension to .txt , i.e. an empty file is saved. 

I will check if a flash drive/usb solves the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem

Comment: Same problem windows 10 no anaconda, 4 TB free, newest R Studio, R 4.2

Comment: Same problem. Windows 10, R 4.2.